# not able to remove selected item at listbox

Tags: asp.net, listboxitems

I have my listbox items with multiple string with hyphen and comma included,is it that because I can not delete the selected items?

If so what is the way to delete the items?

Example below -

Eg: item1-item2-item3a,item3b (my listbox item)

```
     Protected Sub btnVisualDeleteCodeAction_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnVisualDeleteCodeAction.Click

     For i As Integer = 0 To lbVisualCodeAction.Items.Count - 1
        lbVisualCodeAction.Items.Remove(lbVisualCodeAction.SelectedValue.ToString)
     Next


     End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following

```
lbVisualCodeAction.Items.RemoveAt(lbVisualCodeAction.SelectIndex)
```

this way you give the index of the selected item. Which in return removes the selected item

Comment: hi george,thanks for your help,but it show the error of 'SelectIndex' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox'. Mine 1 is web method.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (although not quite sure about the syntax for vb)

```
ListItem myItem = ListBox1.SelectedItem
lbVisualCodeAction.Items.Remove(myItem)
```